# Perform a search on an individual column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

This is probably a very basic newbe question. I need to cretea a method to search within a model on a single column. The model is called Video. I want to search on the title column. I'm thinking the method should look something like this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.sear_for_video_by_title(search_phrase)
    #do the search here
  end
end
```

I'm just not sure what the correct syntax is to do something like this. I think I need to use the like keyword. Maybe something like this:

```
video = Video.were(:title).like(search_phrase)
```

I'm sure that's way off, but that's the basic logic I'm going for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Ruby on Rails 3 with ActiveRecord 3.2.x, you could do:

```
video = Video.where("title like ?", "%#{params[:search_phrase]}%")
```

Will return the results you want.  But there are a couple of things you need to think about here.

1. Wild card string searches are very expensive database-wise.  You need to think about storing metadata like keywords, and searching via those keywords.
2. You need to read up on SQL Injection, and be aware of why it's a big thing and how you can avoid it through techniques like the method above.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
Video.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search_phrase}%")
```

And make a scope of it:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_title_like, ->(phrase) { where('title LIKE ?', "%#{phrase}%") }
```

Usage:

```
@videos = Video.with_title_like('Jurassic')
```

---

You could improve this research method:

- split on each space of the `phrase` and search for each term,
- make is case-insensitive,
- expand the research on other fields (like `description` field)